# Test whether shape is a specific shape ie button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many shape objects. The shapes contain text. I'm using  [a script](https://excel.tips.net/T011281_Finding_Text_in_Text_Boxes.html) to emulate a text search. I've added two buttons - one for "search" (to run `FindInShape2`) and one to "clear" the formatting that was applied by the search (ie run `ResetFont`). (I've had to add `On Error Resume Next` just inside each loop). I have formatted the text on those buttons. My issue is that the "clear" script resets the formatting on the buttons.

To resolve this I'm looking for a test that is logically "if the current shape is not a button".

The local variable name for the shape object is `shp`. The key line populating this is:

```
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
```

I need something like

```
if shp.name not like 'Button%'
```

Note, the display texts on the buttons are "find" and "clear" but when I select the buttons they are named "Button 1" and "Button 2".

Any suggestions? Open to other methods of solving.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marucciboy2's comment put me on the path to an answer.

The code that works is:

```
If shp.Type <> 8 Then
```

In addition to the [docs on the Shape Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.type), the [docs on msoShapeType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) map the type values (ie numbers) with descriptions of the shape types encountered.

In this case, type 8 matches the button controls.

As a bonus, the below will (crudely) aggregate the shape types encountered when looping through `ActiveSheet.Shapes`:

```
Dim sShapeTypes As String

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sShapeTypes = sShapeTypes & ", " & shp.Type
Next

MsgBox sShapeTypes
```

If you have many shapes, the message box won't accommodate a long message. You can use an `If` statement to exclude some that you see appear in the message box.

```
If shp.Type <> 17 Then ' Ignores msoTextBox
    sShapeTypes = sShapeTypes & ", " & shp.Type
End If
```

Comment: Good for you, glad to see someone following up and answering their own problems!